# Push notification through Parse using TestFlight

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, push-notification

I know there are many question like this out there but I have tried multiple things and I still can't seem to get Push notifications to work through Parse with Apps installed through Test flight.

If I Connect my phone and download the app through Xcode, It works perfect. But if I upload the same build to Testflight and try to send a push, Nothing happens.

Some people have said that theres production certificate and developer certificate. Or it could be sandbox tokens. But I'm not sure how to fix these issues.

I already added production and development SSL Certificates to Parse.

PS. Im Building with a developer Provisioning Profile and I Export a AD HOC Developer.

My App Delegate Code is ..

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"----I have mine in----"
                  clientKey:@"----I have mine in----"];
    //-- Set Notification
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }

    //--- your custom code
    return YES;
}





- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}
```

If you need other code I will provide. 
How do I get Push Notifications to Work through Test Flight

Comment: I have nothing to add to this to help, but i am seeing the same issues and was wondering if you had managed to resolve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm answering my own question: 
Your provisioning profile must contain a push certificate for production/ distribution  (still has to be a developer profile though) .
Since test flight works on a production level it won't work with just a developer push certificate (add both).
Any other question on this just ask. I've gone through a lot of trouble shooting

Comment: I'm having the same issue now, but am not too concerned about the pushes working in TestFlight. As long as they work on my test device after downloading directly from Xcode, they should work if/when released onto the App Store, correct?

Comment: Downloading directly from xCode and the app store will be different I believe. ITunes connect test flight should give you a better sense of how it will act from the app store

Comment: What does your project's build settings "Code Sign" and "Provisioning Profile" looks like? Can you show a screenshot? Thanks!

Comment: Also, I guess you were not talking about Apple Testflight? Did you manage to get it working with Apple Testflight?

Comment: I don't have any apps in the new Apple test flight that are using push notification. If you want , feel free to create a question on stackOverflow with images and code of how yours is set up and I will look at it and see if I can spot the problem. Post the link here. PS. Make sure to blur out any part of the image that contains personal info.(you can use the preview app to do that).